# jQuery appending a table made from the AJAX data issues

Tags: jquery, append

EDIT 2 -
Thank you to everyone who looked at this. You all gave me ideas. The actual layout and calling of table was correct through jQuery. The issue seemed to be when the pop up this table was in loaded, it had already loaded the table. It was not waiting for the pop-up to actually open. Thus when the pop up opened, it didnt again trigger the AJAX call with the jQuery `.append()`. The answer is below.

EDIT 1 -
it seems that the issue could be when I launch the popup this is in, its not loading the jquery again. It loads initially with the page though. I have now wrapped the initial jquery in an `.on()` function and tried, on load, click, and open but it now isnt triggering. Is there a better DOM even to use?

I am filling in an HTML table with data from an AJAX request. I have checked `console.log` so I know the AJAX request is good. It posts to the console just fine. So I wish to take that data and build a table out of it to display.

I am using the code below however I can not get that data to `.append()` and show in the table. I have tried `.append()`, `.appendTo()` and even `.after()`. Nothing. I have given the table an ID, the `tbody` an ID, both of them an ID etc yet nothing shows.

**HTML**

```
<table width='100%' border='0' style='display:inline-table' id='cats'>
    <thead><tr> <th>Breed</th><th>Name</th></tr></thead> 
    <tbody ></tbody>    
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                data: {action: 'cats_list'},
                type: 'post',
                url: my_ajax.ajax_url,  
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function(data) {


    jQuery.each( data, function( i, val ) { 
    jQuery('#cats tbody').append('<tr><td>'+val.Name+'</td><td>'+val.Breed+'</td></tr>');
    console.log(val);
    });     
}       
});     
});
```

I have used variations of the table and body combo including

```
jQuery('#cats > tbody')
jQuery('#cats > tbody:last-child')
```

With none of this will it display.

**Data code example**

```
++++++++++++++++
++Breed  ++ Name++++
++Siamese++wiskers++
++++++++++++++++
```

**console data**
Object { id: "43", Breed: "Siamese", Name: "Wiskers" }

Comment: Please provide an example of the contents of `data`.

Comment: added the sample data from the db above

Comment: So when you `console.log(val.Name)` and `val.Breed` it printed out the correct values??

Comment: your jquery code is placed in ajax response right? And table is static from first page load right? You probably have to post more code for help.

Comment: Can you paste the exact console obj that is produced when you `console.log(data)` after your ajax call is made?

Comment: @mohamed-yousef yes. The console correctly logs each of the results I would expect to see in the table itself

Comment: @daremachine yes the jquery is inside the ajax. I have updated above with the code itself so folks can see.

Comment: @dalelandry sure I have added the exact response from the console

Comment: So `data` is an array of objects or just that one single object?

Comment: it can be an array of objects when I enter more. I have been working on this and it seems that the issue could be when I launch the modal this is in, its not loading the jquery again. It loads initially with the page though. I have now wrapped the initial jquery in an `.on()` function and tried, on load, click, and open but it now isnt triggering. Is there a better DOM even to use?

Comment: So when you `console.log(val)` from your forEach loop, do you get a result in console? Have you tried `for(let type in data){ console.log(type) }`?

Comment: Yes I do indeed get results for the loop verifying the `each()` is working ok. The posted code above does have the `console.log(val)` which comes directly from the  `each()`. Take a peek at my comment above. Still havent figured it out but it might mean something to someone smarter than I am, like yourself

Answer (score 0):

For an explanation please see edit #2
The answer was to wrap the initial jquery

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'elementor/popup/show', () => { // add here the other ajax and jquery 
}
```